# Error 404 running Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm new to Eclipse and to Java Web app but i have to work to a project for school on databases.
I created an Eclipse project form the template they gave us and installed Tomcat v7.0
When I start Tomcat "manually" with `startup.sh` it start nicely and shows the tomcat homepage to `localhost:8080`. But when I try to run the project from eclipse on both `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/IntroDBProject`it shows the 404 error report.

I already tried copying the `ROOT`folder in `../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/webapps/`  (and restarting eclipse) but still it doesn't seem to work.

Can someone help?

I'm working on Mac OSX 10.9.2 / Eclipse Java EE IDE / Tomcat v7.0

Comment: Have you added tomcat as a "server" in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I did. that was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem.
I simply deleted and reimported the project. I should have done that earlier. I feel dumb -.-